# How to filter values from a query against a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, sql-like

I've a query that works OK against a MySQL database, but we've had to migrate the database and applications to SQL Server.  Now I'm in trouble getting this query to work.

```
SELECT  
   complist.CompName, 
   complist.CompID, 
   componenttrace.Remark, 
   complist.McID, 
   complist.Station, 
   complist.Slot, 
   complist.Amount - complist.Used - ISNULL(complist.Correction,0) 
FROM 
   complist, componenttrace 
WHERE 
   complist.McID = 1004 
   AND complist.CompID = componenttrace.CompID 
   AND UPPER(complist.Station + '.' + complist.Slot) LIKE '%1.1%'
ORDER BY 
   complist.CompName, complist.CompID
```

On the application, the part that goes

```
AND UPPER(complist.Station + '.' + complist.Slot) LIKE '%1.1%'
```

is added automatically if there's any value on a given field (i.e. `1.1`).

I have a SQL syntax problem, but don't know how to solve it. Can anyone shed some light here?

thanks,

Gustavo

Comment: Exact error message? I copy/pasted the query into SSMS and it parses fine for me.

Comment: is 'Station' and 'Slot' both varchar?

Comment: @M.R., actually, that was the problem, both fields are int. I got it working by adding a CAST(complist.Station AS VARCHAR) and CAST(complist.Slot AS VARCHAR).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without error message is very hard to say what is wrong, but my bet is on the implicit join. Try

```
SELECT  
   complist.CompName, 
   complist.CompID, 
   componenttrace.Remark, 
   complist.McID, 
   complist.Station, 
   complist.Slot, 
   complist.Amount - complist.Used - ISNULL(complist.Correction,0) 
FROM 
   complist
INNER JOIN componenttrace ON complist.CompID = componenttrace.CompID 
WHERE 
   complist.McID = 1004 
   AND UPPER(complist.Station + '.' + complist.Slot) LIKE '%1.1%'
ORDER BY 
   complist.CompName, complist.CompID
```

Comment: I got it working by adding CAST(complist.Station AS VARCHAR) and CAST(complist.Slot AS VARCHAR. My bad! Thanks for the time! :)